# Async code + Async.RunSynchronously vs. plain synchronous code

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#

If I have code like this:

```
let asyncReadToEnd (stream:Stream) = async {
  // Allocate 4kb buffer for downloading data
  let buffer = Array.zeroCreate (4 * 1024)
  use output = new MemoryStream()
  let reading = ref true

  while reading.Value do
    // Download one (at most) 4kb chunk and copy it
    let! count = stream.AsyncRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    output.Write(buffer, 0, count)
    reading := count > 0

  // Read all data into a string
  output.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore

  use sr = new StreamReader(output)
  return sr.ReadToEnd() 
}

use stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream()
asyncReadToEnd stream |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Have I gained anything compared to simply doing

```
use stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream()
use sr = new StreamReader(stream)
sr.ReadToEnd()
```

In both cases I'll have the current thread blocked, but is there still any advantage in terms of freeing thread resources by using the first version?

Comment: That's an interesting question :-). I don't think you gain anything... Just the fact that you now have an async version of the function that you can use elsewhere if you actually need to do things asynchronously.

Comment: Your code is just a rewrite of [`CopyToAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159084.aspx).

Comment: @Daniel, yes I now, but I needed it because this was for .NET 4.0

Comment: @TomasPetricek even in the async case, you'll only be able to progress in the computation after you have consumed the whole stream, so do you actually gain anything in that case?

Comment: In the async case, it matters because you can e.g. do `Async.Parallel` and run _n_ downloads without blocking _n_ threads. To do more than that, you'd need `asyncSeq`: http://tomasp.net/blog/async-sequences.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using `Async.RunSynchronously` on each `async` workflow you've gained nothing. You need to write an entirely asynchronous program to take advantage of it. Then you will be able to do 10,000 concurrently.